# Nested SQL Count

Tags: sql

I have a two tables, Member and Country, what I want to do is find all the countries that have no members.  I am kinda lost, here is my best guess, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT CountryID
FROM Country 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(MemberID) FROM Member WHERE PrCountryID = CountryID) = 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

neojakey

Comment: You can do this via a left join but the syntax would depend on which SQL Package you're using, is it MS SQL/MySQL etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `not exists` clause:

```
SELECT C.CountryID
FROM Country C
WHERE not exists(SELECT 1 FROM Member M WHERE M.PrCountryID = C.CountryID)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.. I never thought to use "NOT EXISTS".. Nice One, 1 Point to you..!

Answer (score 2):

```
select countryID from Country C left join member M on C.CountryID=M.CountryID where M.MemberID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the tables I think you need something like this

```
select * from Country c
left outer join Member m on m.PrCountryID = c.CountryID
where m.PrCountryID is null
```